# JSON ISO Date with seemingly wrong time zone

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, json, json.net

I have the following ISO dates:

```
(UTC) 2013-10-17T05:23:34.387
(PST) 2013-10-17T05:23:34.387-08:00
```

I would like to display the date in PST. (The -08:00 is the offset from UTC to PST)

When I use:

```
alert(new Date('2013-10-17T05:23:34.387'))
alert(new Date('2013-10-17T05:23:34.387-08:00'))
```

I get:

```
Thu Oct 17 2013 06:23:34 GMT +0100 (GMT Summer Time)
Thu Oct 17 2013 14:23:34 GMT +0100 (GMT Summer Time)
```

The ISO date **with no** offset is from the following C# (edited appropriately for this question):

```
item.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime();

/////

var pst = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Pacific Standard Time");
date = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(item.CreatedDate, pst),

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(date, Formatting.Indented);
```

The ISO date **with** an offset is from the following C# (edited appropriately for this question):

```
item.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime();

/////

var pst = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Pacific Standard Time");
var offset = pst.BaseUtcOffset;

date = new DateTimeOffset(TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(item.CreatedDate, pst), offset);

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(date, Formatting.Indented);
```

My question is, how to I maintain the time zone information in the JSON and display the date as PST in the browser?

Comment: "This date should be in PST" - how do you expect anything to know that just from the data? The value doesn't specify it at all. You've just given it a local date/time, with no UTC offset. It happens to have been computed in Pacific Time (not actually PST, by the way - it'll be PDT) but then you've transformed it into a value which removes that information. Given that you've given a "local" value, when you alert on it it's interpreting it as in your client-local time zone.

Comment: I thought it may be something like that. Updated question (PDT, thanks :))

Comment: I suspect you don't *actually* want the full time zone - I suspect you want a date/time with a UTC offset. Try using DateTimeOffset instead of DateTime. Oh, and use DateTime.UtcNow rather than DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime() if you really want a DateTime.

Comment: It's not clear how much of the rest of your code would need to change to use DateTimeOffset instead though. Oh, and consider using Noda Time instead ;)

Comment: I doubt much code. This date is formatted in a simple controller method. Looking into `DateTimeOffset` and `Noda Time` now

Comment: Thinking about it further, I believe a `Date` in Javascript is like a `Date` in Java - it's *just* an instant in time. So if you specify the UTC offset it will give a different result, but it'll still show you the result in BST.

Comment: You are right. The date is converted as BST still. Updated question accordingly.

Comment: Right. So the time zone information now *is* in the JSON - it just can't be in the `Date` object itself. (I'm surprised it's showing at -08 rather than -07, mind you.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [MSN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) about `Date.parse` in javascript:

> The local time zone is used to interpret arguments that do not contain
>   time zone information.

**Update**:
You can keep time zone using Json.NET serialization [settings](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/SerializeDateTimeZoneHandling.htm):

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(date,
    Formatting.Indented,
    new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.Local
    });
```

**Update2**:
About display in javascript.
Yes it maintains the offset, but when it converts date to string it uses local timezone.
Try the following methods:

```
alert(new Date('2013-10-17T05:23:34.387-08:00').toGMTString())
alert(new Date('2013-10-17T05:23:34.387-08:00').toUTCString())
```

Comment: This maintains the offset, but is still interpreted as BST in the browser. Perhaps this is more of a JS issue?

Comment: new Date('2013-10-17T05:23:34.387').toUTCString() was the ticket, thanks! (with no offset you'll notice as the returned time is already in PST time)